# Call a controller method from javascript in visualforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

How can I call a controller method from VisualForce page without any onclick event happening?
My VisualForce page would be like

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"> 

    <script>
     /* Here i need to call a controller class with out any onclick event. It should load by itselef */

    </script>

</apex:page>
```

and my controller class will be like

```
public class OrderPadController {
    /* this will be the constructor */

    public PageReference openPage() {
         PageReference newpage = new Pagereference('/apex'+'/pagetoopen'+'?aid='+a.id); 
         openorderpadembed.setRedirect(false); 
         return openorderpadembed;      
    }
```

From my VisualForce page I need to call the method `openPage()`.

Please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript Remoting for Apex Controllers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) in the following manner:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="OrderPadController">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.$j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j( document ).ready(function() {
        OrderPadController.openPage(function(result, event){

            console.log(result);
            window.open(result,"_self");

        });
      });

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

```apex
public class OrderPadController {
    //

    @remoteAction
    public  PageReference openPage() {
        PageReference newpage = NEW Pagereference('/apex' + '/pagetoopen' + '?aid=' + a.id);
        openorderpadembed.setRedirect(false);
        return openorderpadembed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. In the script

OrderPadController.openPage(function(result, event){ }); what should be the result and event in the function ? I dont have to send anything as a parameter. I am new to this Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that the return values is page reference, I'll go through your case in a few hours, because now I'm on a way to home

Comment: @Ramesh please see my answer again, I've edited it. But please describe your case, I guess that there are options for covering your requirements in more convenient and straightforward manner.

Comment: @Pavel Could you please look at my question? I did what you said and it didn't work. It is about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410030/call-a-controller-method-to-get-download-url-from-javascript-window-onload-in-vi

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="OrderPadController" 
    action="{!openPage}">
</apex:page>
```

the [action](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) parameter will call the method you want as soon as the page loads. It is a dangerous attribute, one that will be pointed out to you if you'll go through Salesforce's security review process. The called action can manipulate database values for example (whereas the OrderPadController constructor can't) and the philosophy is that act of visiting a page shouldn't have any side effect.

In your specific scenario you can do it even without any Apex code at all:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" 
    action="/apex/Gantt?aid={!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}">
    Look Mom, no hands!
</apex:page>
```

---

As Pavel mentions - please write more about your requirement. I suspect that you don't even need this visualforce page acting as redirect, that a simple custom link or button (type = url instead of Visualforce or Javascript) could do the trick...